# Convert rows to column headers with totals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    g.Gender, 
    a.AgeGroup,
    count(*) as Count
FROM 
    client c
INNER JOIN AgeGroup a
    ON c.age BETWEEN a.StartRange AND a.EndRange
INNER JOIN Gender G on
    C.GenderID = G.GenderID
group by
    g.Gender, 
    a.AgeGroup
order by AgeGroup, Gender
```

which gives the following results:

```
Gender      AgeGroup    Count
Male        <=25        4
Unknown     <=25        2
Female      >35         2223
Male        >35         6997
Transgender >35         43
Unknown     >35         2
Female      26-35       413
Male        26-35       590
Transgender 26-35       5
```

What I'm needing to try and do though is convert the Gender column to column headers and include totals.

```
AgeGroup    Male    Female  Trans   Unknown Total
<= 25:      4       0       0       2       6
26 - 35:    590     413     5       0       1008
> 35:       6997    2223    43      2       9265
Total:      7591    2636    48      4       10279
```

I've got this far:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        g.Gender as [Gender], 
        a.AgeGroup
FROM 
    client c
INNER JOIN AgeGroup a
    ON c.age BETWEEN a.StartRange AND a.EndRange
INNER JOIN Gender G on
    C.GenderID = G.GenderID
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Gender)
    FOR [Gender] IN (Male,Female,Transgender,Unknown)
)AS pvt
```

which returns this:

```
AgeGroup    Male    Female  Transgender Unknown
<=25        4       0       0           2
26-35       590     413     5           0
>35         6997    2223    43          2
```

But I don't have the totals.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: try looking up _pivot with count_, plenty of [examples on the site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+pivot+with+count).

Comment: also please try to post everything as text,if possible .In your case(expected and actual results).also try including sample DDL,DML statements

Comment: Thanks @Tanner, managed to figure that out and have updated my post. I can't figure out how to get the totals though.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - is that enough information now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
SELECT *,
(select sum(v)
from
(values(male),
      (female),
      (transgender),
      (unknown))
       as val(v)) as total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        g.Gender as [Gender], 
        a.AgeGroup
FROM 
    client c
INNER JOIN AgeGroup a
    ON c.age BETWEEN a.StartRange AND a.EndRange
INNER JOIN Gender G on
    C.GenderID = G.GenderID
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Gender)
    FOR [Gender] IN (Male,Female,Transgender,Unknown)
)AS pvt
```

**For updated requirement:**
i recommend putting entire table into Some temp table for readabilty and do this

So your above query would go like this

```
SELECT *,
(select sum(v)
from
(values(male),
      (female),
      (transgender),
      (unknown))
       as val(v)) as total
into #temp
from
rest of pivot query
```

and then do grouping for total

```
select 
case when grouping(agegroup)=1 then 'total' else agegroup end agegroup,
sum(male) as male,
sum(female) as 'female',
sum(trans) as 'trans',
sum(unknown) as 'unknown',
sum(total) as 'Total'
 from #temp
 group by 
 grouping sets
 (
 (agegroup),
 ()
 )
```

Comment: Thanks. Gives this error though: Msg 8158, Level 16, State 1, Line 135
'val' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: The Val should be like this.values (male),(female)..I will update once I am near a computer.probably in next 1 hour

Comment: By the way, rather than doing Male,Female,Transgender,Unknown is it possible to replace that with getting the values dynamically from the table?

Comment: @James: see updated,you will have to use dynamic pivot for that

Comment: thanks, the edited query works with totals along the right. There needs to be totals along the bottom too though. Can you help with that please?

Comment: I recommend reading and embracing this link,to know how to ask good questions:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ and also improve chances of getting answer faster

Comment: Thanks for that @TheGameiswar and apologies for the confusing question.